# Is there any clean way to animate control between pages?

Tags: wpf, silverlight

The request is this:
I have a main frame in my main view, that contains several pages.
The first page is logon page, that contains a logon user control.

My goal is moving to the second page in the same frame, and animate the logon control that will eventually become a welcome panel in the next page.

I want the first page to fade out, and the main page to fade in. that i know to do, but in the same time to animate the relevant control to from one page to another without fading and become a child of the second page?

it sounds very significant to applications like Great UI ATM machines or so.

btw, if you have any suggestions to do it other way besides frame and pages, let me know, please.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can, please see telerik control for silverlight, there is a control for this work,
and Very helpfulو [**RadTransitionControl**](http://www.telerik.com/products/silverlight/transition.aspx)

Comment: Well it is a great solution that i know for beautiful transitions, but it still doesn't support my goal - during the transition, begin an animation of a spcific control, that will "float" from one page to another.